# Python REGEX to exclude beggining of string

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation

Given the following string:

`dpkg.log.looker.test.2019-09-25`

I'd want to be able to extract:

`looker.test`
or

`looker`.

I have been trying multiple combinations but none that actually extract only the hostname. If I try to filter the whole beggining of the file (dpkg.log.), it also ignores the subsequent characters:
`/[^dpkg.log].+(?=.[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})/`

returns: 
`er.test`

Is there a way to ignore the whole string "dpkg.log" without ignoring the subsequent repeated characters?

Comment: `s.split('.')[2]`? Should be enough if you need `looker`. Otherwise, what is the right hand boundary criterion?

Comment: If you mean that matching should stop at the date, try `^dpkg\.log\.(.*?)\.\d{2}(?:\d{2})?-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}$`. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/MVZy3b/1). This is a bit verbose though.

Comment: FWIW `[^dpkg.log]` is simply ensuring that character at that position doesn't match any of the characters in `dgklop.` (not the string `dpkg.log` - it means any character not in the set `[^.......]`)

Comment: Ok, looks like a classic string between two strings extraction issue. Use a capturing group and get the value via `match.group(1)`.

Comment: The answer given by @Wiktor Stribiżew is accurate. Thank you.

The following regex will match anything after "dpkg.log." and before the date at the end of the file:

`^dpkg\.log\.(.*?)\.\d{2}(?:\d{2})?-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}$`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, the following expression would be working just OK with `re.findall`:

```
[^.]+\.[^.]+\.(.+)\.\d{2,4}-\d{2}-\d{2}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GEwGVV/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r'[^.]+\.[^.]+\.(.+)\.\d{2,4}-\d{2}-\d{2}'
string = '''
dpkg.log.looker.test.2019-09-25
dpkg.log.looker.test1.test2.2019-09-25
'''

print(re.findall(regex, string))
```

#### Output

```
['looker.test', 'looker.test1.test2']
```